# Android SDK tools and SDK manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I want to download the Android SDK tools, without the IDE. but the `sdkmanager` command couldn't load the `repositories.cfg` file.  How can this be accomplished?

[image: image of the error]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reinstall the sdk but before doing so try to do this:

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

if you are using Linux if windows then put your directory.